# When concatenating why should I change numerical value of "estimated_time" into str()?

Tags: python, string, concatenation

```
def trip_planner_welcome (name):
    print("Welcome to tripplanner v1.0 " + name)
    
def destination_setup(origin, destination, estimated_time, mode_of_transport="Car"):
    print("Your trip starts off in " + origin)
    print("And you are traveling to " + destination)
    print("You will be traveling by " + mode_of_transport)
    print("It will take approximately " + estimated_time + " hours")
```

I got an error that estimate_time should be put in str(). Why can't numbers be numbers when it's being concatenated in between strings?

Comment: Because it's ambiguous. Using `+` on two strings means concatenation. Using `+` on two numbers means addition. If you convert the string to an integer, or convert the integer to a string, it is unambiguous what you mean.

Comment: "Why can't ... ?" Well, they could have designed Python to work that way, but they didn't want to. Some languages, like javascript, will implement all sorts of implicit type coercions in places like this. But lots of people find this surprising and confusing behaviour. The counter-point is, "Why can't you just let numbers be numbers and strings be strings and convert between them when you need to?"

Answer (score 0):

As @NickODell said on the comments `+` operator has different meanings depending on the types it is used on, you can either convert the numerical value `(int)` to `str` or you can use `f strings` which does this conversion automatically:

```py
print(f"It will take approximately {estimated_time} hours")
```